# How to style a Pandas dataframe cell by cell based on an auxiliary matrix?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Suppose I have a simple dataframe of 2x2 size. In the color_matrix of the same size as the dataframe, it stores the color for each cell.

Question: How to style the dataframe given the color matrix? Also need to make sure the dataframe can be saved as an Excel file which has all the colorings.

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
color_matrix = [['Yellow', 'Red'],
                ['Green', 'Blue']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

When I read about the use examples of `df.style.applymap`, it conditions on individual value, but not seems using the index.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an auxiliary function that takes the data frame, and returns a similarly-shaped data frame containing the CSS attribute strings.  In this case, the function prepends the `background-color:` CSS attribute string:

```py
def colors(df, color_matrix):
    # TODO: check sizes and resize color_matrix if necessary
    style_df = pd.DataFrame(color_matrix, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    return style_df.applymap(lambda elem: "background-color:" + elem.lower())
```

Then apply it with [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and `axis=None` (this is important):

```py
df.style.apply(colors, axis=None, color_matrix=color_matrix)
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of styled dataframe]